# Recalculation logic of counting upvotes

Tags: discussion, reputation-recalc

I was just thinking if the Reputation recalc logic also takes into account the daily cap for a user? Below is example data to explain what I mean -

Assume a user has got 25 upvotes for one answer in a day. Since the daily cap is 200, the reputation would've only counted 20 votes. Rest 5 are ignored. But the answer would still be showing 25 upvotes for that user.

Next day or anytime in future, if that user triggers a Reputation-recalc, then does the recalc add the remaining 5 votes to his reputation as well or no? Because as I see, reputation recalc just adds all upvotes on all our questions and answers.

Comment: No, all actions are timestamped so recalcs do not have this problem. (*[citation needed]*)

Comment: @mmyers - I have not seen any issues over this, just asked question for my information about recalc logic. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the reputation recalc takes the cap into account. Otherwise it would have *vastly* increased the reputation of many of the high-rep users.

Shame, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Of all people you say this? :)

Comment: @Sachin: Well it would be quite fun to see an uncapped SO for a few days...

Answer (score 1):

The recalc does not add the remaining 5 votes to the reputation - the daily rep cap still applies.

The recalc changes the reputation for other reasons, for example for rep-modifying factors that aren't immediately applied, such as when a post you have downvoted in the past gets deleted.